# Content profile for two content types as user registration Drupal

Tags: drupal, profile

I want to use content profile for multiple content types for user registration. Like I have business content type that I'll use for user how wants to register as business on my site and I have other as Company where company users will register as Company.

Now I've selected use on registration page but I'm only getting business content type for registration and not company. I want both on different url for registration as they are different roles and content types.

I'm using drupal 6.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Auto Assign Role Module  http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole, you will have to fill the settings in the Assign from Path section in admin/user/autoassignrole, you will find options for each role.

Also you must check the "use on registration" option in the content profile section of each content type.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements best way to use it is to go with [profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [profile2_regpath](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) modules. Combination of these modules allows you to create different user registration form with different fields for different user roles with different urls.

This is link of tutorial where you can find proper step to create this functionality:
http://drupixels.com/blog/registration-multiple-user-roles-different-registration-pages-profile-2-module